# Combinar dos objetos Json en java

Tags: java, json

Tengo dos JSONObject con la misma estructura, pero quiero combinarlos de forma que se mantengas las características en común y que a aquellas que sean diferentes le de prioridad al segundo objeto.

Ejemplo:

```
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject("{
"name":"manu",
"age":23,
"occupation":"SE"
}")

JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject("{
"name":"manu",
"age":23,
"country":"india",
"email" : "foo@bar.com"
}")
```

Esperado:

```
JSONObject result = {
"name":"manu",
"age":23,
"occupation":"SE",
"country":"india",
"email" : "foo@bar.com"
}
```

Intenté con lo siguiente:

```
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject("{\n"
                + "\"name\":\"manu\",\n"
                + "\"age\":23,\n"
                + "\"occupation\":\"SE\"\n"
                + "}");

        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject("{\n"
                + "\"name\":\"manu\",\n"
                + "\"age\":23,\n"
                + "\"country\":\"india\"\n"
                + "}");

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(obj2.toString());

        Iterator<?> keys = obj1.keys();

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) keys.next();
            if (!result.has(key))
                result.put(key, obj1.get(key));
        }
```

Pero no lo considero eficiente, pues lo usaré para Jsons muy grandes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que estás utilizando la mejor solución disponible. Existen librerías que proporcionan métodos para "fusionar" objetos json, pero si inspeccionas su código fuente, hacen exactamente lo que tú estás haciendo (crear un iterator y recorrer los elementos de un objeto para insertarlos en otro). Por tanto creo es más eficiente que lo hagas tú mismo con tu código que cargar una librería completa para usar la misma función.